# parallel calculations on matlab

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing

As discussed in other posts, I understood that some functions are parallelized in Matlab, so they are fast in serial calculations ( like `normxcorr2` which uses FFT functions and `conv2`).

I used this code

```
parfor( i=1:1000,20) % To do calculations on 20 cores only
    y1= function_1(image1, template,....)
    . % other lines
    .
    .
end
```

If inside `function_1` I have FFT functions (like `conv2` `fft2` ,etc) and I allocate to this calculation the remaining cores

```
function y= function_1(image1,template,...)
   parfor( i=1:41,24) % I allocated 24 cores to the child function
      t=template{i};
      correlation{i}=normxcorr2(image1,t),
      %etc
   end
%etc
end
```

Why when I open the task manager ,  in the section " performance" the percent of memory used is only 40% ?

I thought that when i have 44 cores and I allocate 20 to the global calculation and 24 to the functions inside , it will be 99% of memory used.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: You seem to be confusing the number of cores and the amount of RAM.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark and how can I see how much cores are used ? ( on the task manager)

Comment: Task Manager > Performance > CPU Usage

Comment: I think MATLAB will use 20 x 24 cores = 480 cores (in the hypothetical case that you have that many cores)

Comment: In **Task Manager > Performance > CPU Activity** you should see something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8Hja.png), where each plot represents one core (if you see only one - right click on them and choose **Change graph to > Logical processors**). You can also see here how many of them actually work, and in what usage.

Comment: @EBH thank you for the help

Comment: @m7913d thank you !